# Strange order of transactions in the same block

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

recently i saw next thing:
There is a nft game contract, the goal is to be the first (top 100).
Each game starts by Tx from admin, let's say he calls start() function in his transaction.
Then all players are trying to send transaction play().

There are many bots

And recently i saw next order of transactions in the block

0: TX from admin with gasPrice: 30 GWEI

1: TX from player with gasPrice: 1000 GWEI

2: TX from player with gasPRice: 900 GWEI

etc

So the question is why admin tx placed in the block before players TX, if players have paid higher gasPrice. Also wanna mention if players tx appear before admin - tx will fail

Comment: yes, " if players tx appear before admin - tx will fail". that's why

Comment: @ZartajAfser but how do they manage to place their transaction after admins tx? if they have more gasPrice their transaction should be placed in front of admin tx in the same block